# Onclick delate my css code, how not to delete my css code?

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, calendar

I am in the creation of a calendar. The problem is when I change the month by clicking on the back button it loads the new calendar but it does not apply the CSS code to my new calendar.
Do you have an idea ?

```
<section style="width: 36vh;">
    <div id="cal_title"><h4>CALENDAR</h4></div>
    <div id="cal_menu">
        <div id="cal_back" class="button" onclick="var date_month = new Date(year,month-1);calendar(date_month,day);" style="background-image: url(../icones/arrow_back.svg)"></div>
        <div id="cal_month" class="month">March</div>
        <div id="cal_next" class="button" style="background-image: url(../icones/arrow_next.svg)"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var date = new Date();
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var year = date.getYear();
        year = year + 1900;

        // Ici j'aimerai pouvoir changer 'month' 
        var date_month = new Date(year,month);
        calendar(date_month,day); // Fontionne très bien

    </script>
</section>
```

here is the css code which removes it. When I look in the development of Google Chrome, it tells me "== 0 $" next to  and all the  is deleted.

```
#cal_title {
    width: 36vh;
    height: 4vh;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:4vh;
    color: #aaa;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6vh; 
    background-color: #fff;
}

#cal_menu {
    width: 36vh;
    height: 6vh;
}

#cal_menu .button {
    width: 6vh;
    height: 6vh;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-position: center;
}

#cal_menu .month {
    width: 24vh;
    height: 6vh;
    float: left;
    line-height: 6vh;
    text-align: center;
    color: #154E5B;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3vh; 
}

.calendar{
    width: 36vh;

    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5vh;
}

.calendar th {
    height: 4.5vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #154E5B;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.calendar .cal_day:hover {
    background-color: #154E5B;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.calendar .cal_today {
    background-color: #154E5B;
    color: #fff;
}

.calendar .circle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius:5vh;
    line-height: 4.5vh;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    /*background-color: #7ed6df;   si il y a quelque chose*/
}

.calendar .cal_otherMonth {
    color: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: Share the CSS code.

Comment: It is ok for the css code